# find and replace from another table mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I need to find and replace multiplie strings  from table "phrases" using table "dict"

I have code like:

```
update  phrases, dict
set     phrases.name = replace(phrases.name, dict.source, dict.translate)
where   phrases.name <> replace(phrases.name, dict.source, dict.translate)
```

pharses table example:

```
id | name | .. | ..
1  | macbook wht comput | ..
2  | lenova blck god nb | ..
```

dict table example:

```
id | source | translate 
1  | wht    | white
2  | god    | good
3  | lenova | lenovo
4  | blck   | black
5  | comput | computer
6  | nb     | notebook
```

I need get to phares like this:

```
id | name | .. | ..
1  | macbook white computer | ..
2  | lenova black good notebook | ..
```

It will replace only 1 string at once in row, but I have about 3-10 strings to replace.

How this code can be changed to replace all strings in rows?

Comment: can you provide a few rows of example data, please?

Comment: @user2421781 Have you checked this post?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find and replace string in MySQL using data from another table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509835/find-and-replace-string-in-mysql-using-data-from-another-table)

Comment: i tryed this, but unfourtunely

Answer (score 1):

**Create function and use it for update**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION translate_phrases_name(phraseId numeric)
  RETURNS character varying AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
phrasesString character varying;
newPhrasesString character varying;
currentWord character varying;
currentWordTranslation character varying;
i numeric;
wordsCount numeric;


BEGIN

phrasesString := (select name from phrases where id = phraseId);
--the string that u want to get, we will use it later
newPhrasesString := phrasesString;

phrasesString := trim(phrasesString);

phrasesString := regexp_replace(phrasesString, '\s+', ' ', 'g');

wordsCount := length(regexp_replace(phrasesString, '[^ ]+', '', 'g'));
--the count of the words is +1 more than count of spaces
wordsCount := wordsCount + 1;


--working with each word 
for i in 1..wordsCount loop
    --find first word in string
    currentWord := substring(phrasesString from '\A[^ ]+');
    --find translation in dict table
    currentWordTranslation := (select translate from dict where source = currentWord);
    --constructing string that u want
    newPhrasesString := replace(newPhrasesString, currentWord, currentWordTranslation);
    --kill first word for next iteration of loop
    phrasesString := replace(phrasesString, currentWord, '');
end loop;

return newPhrasesString;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION translate_phrases_name(numeric)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

**the final update will be:**

```
update phrases
    set name = (select translate_phrases_name(id));
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe not a very nice solution but at least one

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_replaceFromTable()
BEGIN

  DECLARE countRowsDict int;
  DECLARE countRowsEpl int;
  DECLARE currDict int;
  DECLARE currExample int;
  DECLARE d_source varchar(255);
  DECLARE d_translate varchar(255);

  SELECT count(id) into countRowsDict from dict;
  SELECT count(id) into countRowsEpl from pharses;
  SET currDict = 0;
  SET currExample = 0;

  WHILE currExample < countRowsEpl DO

    SET currDict = 0;

    WHILE currDict < countRowsDict DO

      SELECT source INTO d_source FROM dict LIMIT currDict, 1;
      SELECT translate INTO d_translate FROM dict LIMIT currDict,1;

      UPDATE pharses SET text = REPLACE(text, d_source, d_translate);

      SET currDict = currDict + 1;
    END WHILE;

    set currExample = currExample + 1;
  END WHILE;

END//
```

problem with this is it will replace comput with computerer because there is comput in computer so it's replaced twice

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Comment: used that syntax to check in sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d919b, you probably have to change // with ; at the end

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
UPDATE  phrases, 

(SELECT id, replaced FROM (
   SELECT (@cntr := @cntr + 1) cnt, id, 
   @temp := REPLACE(COALESCE(IF(@tempID  <> ID, NULL,  @temp), NAME), source, translate) replaced, 
   @tempID := ID  FROM (

        SELECT @cntr := 0, @tempID := 0, @temp := NULL, phrases.id, NAME, source, translate
        FROM  phrases, dict 
       ORDER BY ID DESC 
   ) a ORDER BY cnt DESC 
) b GROUP BY ID DESC ) derivedTable 

SET    phrases.name = derivedTable.replaced
WHERE   phrases.id = derivedTable.id;
```

This is not a smooth way. But definitely in a single query. Try running the inner query separately to figure out how it works!

Comment: #1052 - Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: Edited the answer.. Pls try now

Comment: #126 - Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_1889_3.MYI'; try to repair it

Comment: Try this query with sample tables with few records to understand how it workks. Later you can use it for bigger tables with right set of indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will this will solve your problem.

```
DECLARE @DictId INT
DECLARE @MaxId INT
SET @DictId = 1
SELECT @MaxId = MAX(id) FROM dict

DECLARE @Source NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Translate NVARCHAR(MAX)
WHILE (@DictId <= @MaxId)
BEGIN
    SELECT
        @Source = source
        ,@Translate = translate
    FROM dict
    WHERE id = @DictId

    UPDATE pharses
    SET name = REPLACE(name,@Source,@Translate)
    SET @DictId = @DictId + 1
END
```

What this script will do is iterate through the dict table, and replace any words found in the phrases table that match the dict.source field with its corresponding dict.translate.

Comment: Could you please explain more your solution

Comment: Added a brief detail on how my proposed solution work.