# LIKE operator in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

I want to get all the records from the one table which contain at least one word from the input string. For example, input parameter='**Stack over flow**':

```
select *
from sample
where  name like '%stack%'
    or name like '%over%'
    or name like '%flow%'
```

How do I search for records which contains 'stack' or 'over' or 'flow'?

Comment: @codeka: i think the question is "What is the code?...How do do it?"

Comment: @hallie: I think I get it, he wants code that will transform the string "stack over flow" into an SQL query that will search for any name containing "stack" *or* "over" *or* "flow". The next question, then, is what language?

Comment: I dont see why it is not working as is.

Comment: i have tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507330/sqlserver-split-operation sample to split the string. Its working. i dont know how to get this task

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you gave should work.  But don't use it.  It won't be able to use any indexes, and so will likely be very slow.  Look into a full text index and the CONTAINS keyword instead.

Comment: Short of that, a regex could be used if CLR is enabled.

Comment: It sounds like there is only one input parameter that he needs parsed and then a like for each word.

Comment: Absolutely correct. Like with a wildcard as the first character is almost always a bad thing as it forces a table scan and full-text indexing will work much better.

Comment: I agree using leading wildcards with the LIKE is going to make this perform really badly, but if the table is small it won't matter that much.  If it is a large table definitely full text index with contains.  It appears he already has an answer from a different question on how to split the parameter into words.

Comment: @OMG - a Regular expression would still need to perform a table scan