# splitting a row in sql with different information in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a row in my database that has a string with lots of different information.

For example if my row is notes and each row contains something like:
a|b|c
how do I put each into a separate column and name each of the columns? I was just using substring but the information that has to be separated has different starting positions

edit:
Table notes

Column notes, each row contains something like"Address: 123 main st | name: bob | Date: 1/1/2012" I need each item in its own column and labeled accordingly. The | is actually in the  row to break up the data.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507330/sqlserver-split-operation

Comment: Nah, I am wanting something like if the row notes had something like "date: 2/2/2011 | address: 123 main st | state: FL"  I want it to split each into there own separate column like Date as the header and the date as its row, then a new column with address as header and the address as its row. and so forth.  But I have multiple rows in the original notes table