# De-sequence a Varchar (List) Then Execute INSERT(s) per Item as a TRIGGER

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, triggers

We have a table of User ID's with a varchar column that turns out to be a list of foreign keys. Why is it a list and not a reference, because it has to be :/

```
USERID  CLASSES_ATTENDED
100099  01052013,02042013,04302013,06042013
```

A table does exist that matches these classes to their names, but we have no way of list the class name to the user id.

```
CLASS     NAME
01052013  MATH
02042013  SCIENCE
04302013  COMPUTERS
06042013  COOKING
```

The only solution available to me is to use an after insert trigger on the varchar CLASSES_ATTENDED column that will read each "key" one-by-one and then insert the USERID/CLASS records(s) in another table.

How do I de-sequence the list then execute one INSERT statement for each item within a trigger declaration?

I have SQLServer 2005, with a Management Studio non-SSIS installation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you want the split function.  Here is a reference . . . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507330/sql-server-split-operation.  However, your question doesn't actually explain what you want to do.  What is the question?

Comment: Thanks for the link! My question is near the bottom: How do I de-sequence the list then execute one INSERT statement for each item within a trigger declaration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CROSS APPLY clause did the trick!

```
SELECT U.USERID, T.item AS CLASS
FROM bad_table U
CROSS APPLY split(M.CLASSES, ',') AS T
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to "desequence" the data is to use a join.

```
insert into ProperJunctionTable(userid, class)
    select t.userid, c.class
    from table t join
         classes c
         on ',' + t.classes_attended + ',' like '%,' + c.class + ',%';
```

However, it is likely that `split()` will perform better.

By the way, if you don't like user defined functions for some reason, you can implement `split()` using a recursive CTE.

Comment: I'm not following why you're adding the the commas? My system doesn't seem to like the second set, the ones surrounding the c.class.

Comment: @user2888449 . . . The commas delimit the values so "10" won't match "100".  They may not be necessary in this case.